# A problem with Email Transport in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a problem with Email Transport in my Cakephp 3. I am setting default Email Transport to Debug and Cakephp 3 said me that I don't have ... an Email Transport.

[image: My Error]

I am tired to change the name of Email Transport, className and Include it inside Mailer but nothing happen.

Here is my code in App.php

```php
    'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Mail',
            /*
             * The following keys are used in SMTP transports:
             */
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 25,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => null,
            'password' => null,
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
    ],

    /**
     * Email delivery profiles
     *
     * Delivery profiles allow you to predefine various properties about email
     * messages from your application and give the settings a name. This saves
     * duplication across your application and makes maintenance and development
     * easier. Each profile accepts a number of keys. See `Cake\Mailer\Email`
     * for more information.
     */
    'Email' => [
        'default' => [
            'transport' => 'default',
            'from' => 'you@localhost',
            //'charset' => 'utf-8',
            //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
        ],
    ],
```

My CountForm::_execute()

```php
protected function _execute(array $data)
    {
        $Mail = new Email('default');

        return ($this->getMailer('Counter', $Mail)->send('sendCounterFromEbok', [$data]) && $this->getMailer('Counter', $Mail)->send('greetingsFromEbok', [$data]));
    }
```

My CakePhp version is 3.7.0

Comment: What does your `CountForm::_execute()` code look like, and how are you applying the `EmailTransport` and `Email` configuration in your `config/bootstrap.php` file?

Comment: Thanks for replay @ndm. I have `EmailTransport` and `Email` code  in app.php. In `config/bootstrap.php` I have `Email::setConfig(Configure::consume('EmailTransport'));` only. I edit my original post and add `CountForm::_execute()` for you.

Comment: Problem solved. I add `->setTransport('default')` to my code in CounterMailer.php. It's strange. Never used before.